# Reset counter after last button click + n of seconds

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a simple code for counting button clicks

```
btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private int counter = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter++;
        textOutput.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }
}
```

and I want to implement counter reset function after n amount of time (i.e. 1 second) after last button click.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), one you restart after every button press by calling `restart()` on it.

Comment: @Toesmash Are you trying to implement a detection for `double click`?

Comment: Please see edit to answer with code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll let you write your own code for this but the steps are simple:

- Create a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and in its ActionListener, simply reset count to 0, and display this in the textOutput component.
- In the Timer's constructor, pass in the timer delay int -- however long you want to give the user before the count re-sets, as well as the ActionListener above.
- Make the Timer non-repeatable by calling `setRepeats(false)` on it.
- In your button's ActionListener, simply call `restart()` on the counter after setting the text of textOutput.
- Note that you can't declare your counter field within your JButton's ActionListener as you're doing it since that limits its scope too much, **unless** the button's ActionListener also has getter and setter fields for this value which the Timer's ActionListener can call.

---

I wasn't going to show code, but since someone else did, I'm somewhat obliged. Please see comments in code that explain.

Key is the Timer's ActionListener. All it does is reset's the counter

```
    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setCounter(0);  // this is all the timer does
        }
    }
```

Note that in my code, the `setCounter(int counter)` method set's the int counter value **and displays it in a JLabel**:

```
// method that sets counter value **and** displays value in JLabel
public void setCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
    counterLabel.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
}
```

The JButton's ActionListener is actually an `AbstractAction` class, somewhat like an ActionListener "on steroids". It does all that an ActionListener does, and also sets the button's text and gives the button a mnemonic key, and can do more as well. All it does is advance the counter and calls `restart()` on the Timer, that's it:

```
    // ActionListener (and more) for the button
    private class ButtonPressAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonPressAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);  // text to show in button
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);  // alt-key mnemonic key for button
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setCounter(counter + 1);  // re-sets the counter and displays it
            timer.restart();   // re-sets and runs the timer
        }
    }
```

The whole program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ResetCounter extends JPanel {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000; // 1 second delay
    private int counter = 0;  // our counter field
    private JLabel counterLabel = new JLabel("   0   ", SwingConstants.CENTER); // label to display counter value
    private JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonPressAction("Click Me", KeyEvent.VK_C));  // our button with its AbstractAction
    private Timer timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()); // the Swing Timer loaded with its delay and ActionListener

    public ResetCounter() {
        // make sure timer does not repeat
        timer.setRepeats(false);

        // create JPanel to hold JLabels that give counter information
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Count:"));
        topPanel.add(counterLabel);

        // JPanel to hold the button
        JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
        midPanel.add(button);
        int ebGap = 15; // make mid panel bigger
        midPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(ebGap, ebGap, ebGap, ebGap));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(midPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // method that sets counter value **and** displays value in JLabel
    public void setCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
        counterLabel.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }

    // ActionListener (and more) for the button
    private class ButtonPressAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonPressAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);  // text to show in button
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);  // alt-key mnemonic key for button
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setCounter(counter + 1);  // re-sets the counter and displays it
            timer.restart();   // re-sets and runs the timer
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setCounter(0);  // this is all the timer does
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ResetCounter mainPanel = new ResetCounter();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ResetCounter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Reset counter after last button click + n of seconds

If you want to keep track of the time by yourself, you can make use of Swing.Timer:

[image]

In the demo, the number of clicks will reset to 0 for every 5 seconds.

I created timer to "tick" at an interval of approximately every 1 second. The timer will only be triggered when the button is clicked and elapsed time (`variable int time`) will start ticking. When the elapsed time equals to the delay (`variable int delayInSeconds`) , it will reset the count for number of clicks (`variable int clicks`)  and stop the timer.

The entire process will repeat when the user clicks on the button again.

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Timer timer;
    private JButton btn;
    private JLabel lblTime, lblClicks;  
    private int clicks, time, delayInSeconds;

    public MainPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        initComponents();
        addComponents();    
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        time = 0;           //elapsed time in seconds
        clicks = 0;         //clicks accumulated
        delayInSeconds = 5; //delay to reset click count

        btn = new JButton("Click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        lblTime = new JLabel("Elapsed time: " + time);
        lblClicks = new JLabel("Num of Clicks:" + clicks);          
        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){  
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){             
                time ++;                
                if(time >= delayInSeconds){
                    clicks = 0;
                    time = 0;                   
                    timer.stop();                   
                }
                updateDisplay();                
            }               
        });                     
    }

    private void addComponents(){
        add(lblTime);
        add(lblClicks);
        add(btn);                   
    }

    private void updateDisplay(){
        lblClicks.setText("Num of Clicks: " + clicks);
        lblTime.setText("Elapsed time: " + time);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            clicks ++;  //gather clicks
            time = 0;   //reset time count
            timer.start();
            updateDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

A runner class to drive the codes:

```
class ClickCounter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Click Counter");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);             
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** If you intend to use this to detect a double-click or triple-click. Swing already has this feature implemented for you. You could just use `e.getClickCount()`:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getClickCount() == 2)      
        System.out.println(“double click”);
}
```

Comment: @Toesmash You may take a look at this solution.